# Why does og:article have a property for article:author?

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

How does this get surfaced within Facebook/what is FB doing with this data? Same question for article:tag -- why is it useful to tag your article with this property? What is the benefit?

Answer (score 0):

These tags are to be used with the built-in Open Graph action `read`:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/#read

You can see a full definition of all the OG tags here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/objects/builtin/#article